# Create a graph with an adjacency matrix in C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

I was implementing a graph program based on an adjacency matrix in C.
But I am getting a segmentation fault while I am initializing the matrix (assigning the value of zero). 
I am not sure whether I am doing any mistake in accessing double pointers or not.

Can anyone please help me in resolving the issue?

Here is the code:

```
struct Graph {
    int V;
    int E;
    int **adj;
};


struct Graph *addelements() {
    int i,j,a,u,v;  

    struct Graph *G= (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph*));
    printf("Enter the number of vertices and edges : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &G->V,&G->E);;
    printf("%d, %d\n",G->V ,G->E);
    //G->adj = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int **)*(G->V * G->E));
    G->adj = malloc(sizeof(G->V * G->E));

    //Initialization of vertices

    for(i=0;i<=G->V;i++) {
        for(j=0;i<=G->V;j++) {
            G->adj[i][j]=0;
        }
    }


    //Reading the edges;
    for(i=0;i<G->E;i++) {
        printf("Enter the source and destination : ");  
        scanf("%d %d\n", &u,&v);       
        G->adj[u][v]=1;    
        G->adj[v][u]=1;
    }

    //printing the matrix

    for(i=0;i< G->V;i++) {
        for(j=0;i< G->V;j++) {
            printf("%d", G->adj[i][j]);4
        }
    }

   return G;
}


int main() {  
    struct Graph *a= (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph*)); 
    a =  addelements();  
}
```

The output:

> Enter the number of vertices and edges : 4 5
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: BTW, you do know that `sizeof (G->V * G->E)` is the same as `sizeof (int)`?  Perhaps you wanted to `malloc(sizeof *G->adj * G->V * G->E);` instead?

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned your error is there

```
G->adj = malloc(sizeof(G->V * G->E));

//Initialization of vertices

for(i=0;i<=G->V;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<=G->V;j++) 
  {
    G->adj[i][j]=0;
  }
}
```

- You are writing at `adj[V][V]` where you allocated with the size of `sizeof(G->V * G->E)` which would be `sizeof(int)` ( one int ) ,even if you wanted up to `adj[V][E]`
- Additionally you are allocating a 1D array and accessing a 2D array, accessing `adj[0][0]` would first try to read `adj[0]` as a pointer to an array ( an undefined value) and would try to write to `undefined[0]`

Allocate with `malloc( G->V * G->V * sizeof(int) )` and access/write with `adj[i*V+j]`

There quite a few fault in your logic due to what you were expected the code to behave vs how it really understood you. It might be useful to use a debugger to understand where the fault happens and inspect the involved variable.

Edit:

Also as [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50635741/105104) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50635667/105104) mentionned:

you are allocating a size to small for `G` as `malloc(sizeof(struct Graph*))` would be equivalent to `malloc(sizeof(void*))` ( allocating the size of one pointer ), where you shoukd `malloc(sizeof(struct Graph))`

Second Edit:

Noticed a typo in your `j` loop  `for(j=0;i<=G->V;j++)` should be `for(j=0;j<=G->V;j++)`

Comment: its still the same... getting segmentation fault.

Comment: As noted in other comment you also have an issue with `malloc(sizeof(struct Graph*))` where you are allocating space for a pointer, use  `malloc(sizeof(struct Graph))` instead. GDB would should whow where the segfault happens

Comment: Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from graph...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/datastructures/graph 
Enter the number of vertices and edges : 4 5
4, 5

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400702 in addelements ()
(gdb) 
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400702 in addelements ()
#1  0x0000000000400867 in main ()
\(gdb) f 0
#0  0x0000000000400702 in addelements ()
(gdb)

This is what gdb is showing

Comment: don't forget to compile wiht the `-g` flag with would magically make debugging with gdb infinitly more useful

Comment: oops sorry i completely forgot that...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400748 in addelements () at graph.c:44
44       G->adj[i][j]=0;

its showing in this line

Comment: Is `G->adj` a valid pointer, is `G->adj[0]` an `int[]` ( spoiler: no )? Try `adj[i*V+j]`.

Comment: still at the same location ?

Comment: Just noticed a typo in the `j` loop, you should correct it

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to modify

```
struct Graph *G= (struct Graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct Graph*));
```

to

```
struct Graph *G= malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
```

as you need space allocated to store a structure variable not a pointer.

And you haven't allocated space for `G->adj` properly.

Try

```
G->adj = malloc(sizeof(int **));
for(int i=0; i<G->V; ++i)
{
    G->adj[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*G->V);
}
```

And modify your loop to be

```
for(i=0;i<G->V;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<G->V;j++) 
   {
      G->adj[i][j]=0;
   }
}
```

ie, change the `<=` to `<` to prevent accessing out of bounds of the array.

And while reading the edges, don't do

```
scanf("%d %d\n", &u,&v);
```

with the newline at the end. See [this](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfhang.html).

Also, you need to check if the entered values for `u` and `v` are within the limits as in

```
for(i=0;i<G->E;i++)  
{
    printf("Enter the source and destination : ");  
    scanf("%d %d", &u,&v);       
    if(u<G->V && v<G->V)
    {
        G->adj[u][v]=1;    
        G->adj[v][u]=1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\ninvalid value. Try again.");
        i--;
    }
}
```

And you needn't allocate space for that `struct` pointer in  `main()` as you already allocate memory for the value that you will store in that pointer at the `addelements()` function. Otherwise it will lead to memory leak.

So, in `main()`, do

```
struct Graph *a= addelements();
```

Note that `malloc()` returns `NULL` if it failed to allocate memory. You need to check if the `malloc()` calls fail as well.

And you needn't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: i did it... but still it is showing segmentation fault....

its problem with the //Initialization of vertices part...

Comment: @Ankita I've edited my post. See if it works for you.

Comment: @Ankita Still segmentation fault?

Comment: i have used gdb ... it is showing in this particular line...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400748 in addelements () at graph.c:44
44       G->adj[i][j]=0;

Comment: i am not sure what is the correct way of accessing it

Comment: @Ankita Did you `malloc()` for `G->adj` as in my answer? If that's the way you allocated for `adj`, you can access it like `G->adj[i][j]` itself.

Comment: Yup i malloc() for G->adj as you said... i did that changes too... but its stiill the same

Comment: @Ankita Can you post the modified code somewhere and share the link? [ideone](https://ideone.com) maybe?

Comment: @Ankita I can't find the problem. I could find no difference between your code and mine.

Comment: @Ankita Finally got something. You haven't modified the loops. The inner loop for initialising the `adj` array has condition `i<G->V` instead of `j<G->V`. Same in the case of  printing the matrix.

Comment: @Ankita Also, remove the `\n` at the end of the `scanf()`.

Comment: thank you so much for the help... it worked completelyyyy

Answer (score 0):

You are `malloc`ing space for just a pointer. Use instead:

```
malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
```